# PHP ftp_chdir not visibly changing the directory

Tags: php, ftp

I started on an ftp project and I'm having trouble getting the directory to reload.  My code says that it successfully changed, but I am assume that it only changes server-side.  I need the browser to change the directory as well.

PS: How can I download via FTP through the browser?  When I test locally it writes the files to the root directory but when connected remotely I don't know where they go.  There is no indication of files being downloaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  And please, if you have any tips for me that would be great.  I'm still pretty new at this but I'm trying my best.

```
<?php
session_id('logon');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['connect']))
{
$_SESSION['port'] = $_POST['port'];
$_SESSION['server'] = $_POST['server'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
$port = $_SESSION['port'];
$server = $_SESSION['server'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$pass = $_SESSION['password'];

$connection = ftp_connect($server)
or die("Couldn't connect!");

$logon = ftp_login($connection,$user,$pass)
or die("Couldn't login!" . $server ."<br>". $port);


$workingDir = ftp_pwd($connection);

echo "You are in $workingDir<br><br>";

$dirList = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");

foreach($dirList as $item)
{
    $res = ftp_size($connection, $item);
    if ($res != "-1")
    {
        echo "<a href='?download=$item'>$item</a><br>";
        if (isset($_GET['download']))
        {
            if ($_GET['download'] == $item)
            {
                include('include/download.php');
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
            $directory = $item;
            echo "<a href='?change=$directory'>$directory</a><br>"; 
            if ($_GET['change'] == $directory)
            {
                    if (ftp_chdir($connection, $directory))
                    {
                        echo "Changed to " . ftp_pwd($connection) . "!<br>";
                        $dirList = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");
                        header("Refresh:0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Failed to change to $directory";
                    }

            }       
    }
}


ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ftp_quit($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!  Added a directory.php file with

```
$getChange = $_GET['change'];

if (ftp_chdir($connection, $getChange))
{
    echo "Changed to " . ftp_pwd($connection) . "!<br>";
    $dirList = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");
}
else
{
    echo "Failed to change to $getChange";
}

$workingDir = ftp_pwd($connection);
echo "You are in $workingDir<br><br>";  

$dirList = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");

foreach($dirList as $item)
{
    $res = ftp_size($connection, $item);

    if ($res != "-1")
    {
        echo "<a href='?download=$item'>$item</a><br>";

        if (isset($_GET['download']))
        {
            if ($_GET['download'] == $item)
            {
                include('include/download.php');
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<a href='directory.php?change=$item'>$item</a><br>";  
    }
}
```